# why my webpages can't break line in Iphone browser?

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari

This is my website for mobiles to visit : [m.looa.com](http://m.looa.com)

If you got an Iphone,please visit it and you will find that the words don't break line .

This only happens in Iphone's browser, it looks fine for android and almost all browsers for PC,including
IE Chrome FireFox and even Safari(you can try that).

I know this must have something to do with CSS but I can't figure out where the problem lies .

Below is the code from my webpage,please pay attention to the class : middigest,I think that probably is where the problem lies(I have delete some code to make it more clear):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='theme/mobile/img/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' /> 
    </head> 
    <body onload='setPage(160)'>
        <div class='allbox'> 
        <dl class='alltop'> 
            <dt class='w2' onclick="window.location.href='http://m.looa.com/g_m_city'"><a>北京</a></dt> 
        <dd><a href='http://m.looa.com/mobile'><img src='theme/mobile/img/looa_logo.png'/></a></dd> 
        <dt class='w3' onclick="window.location.href='http://m.looa.com/g_m_cang'"><a>收藏夹</a></dt> 
        </dl> 

        <dl class='topmid'> 
            <dt><img src='theme/mobile/img/looa_nearby_s.gif' /></dt> 
        <dd onclick= 'getCityDis()'><a> <img src='theme/mobile/img/looa_dis.gif'/></a></dd> 
        </dl> 

        <div class='midbox' id='midbox'> 

          <dl class='midmenu'> 
              <dt>距离<strong> 0.0km</strong></dt> 
              <dd>商家<strong> 纯视觉摄影工作室</strong></dd> 
          </dl> 

          <div class='middigest'> 
              <a href='http://m.looa.com/g_m_detail?deal_id=6921'>性感翘臀，迷人水腰，诱人S曲线，这一站就是你</a>    <----------- this line
          </div> 

          <dl class='midpic'> 
                <dt><a href='http://m.looa.com/g_m_detail?deal_id=6921'><img width='175px' height='129px' src='http://www.looa.com/theme/tuan/outsite_deal_img/201010/1287700044_small.jpg'/></a></dt> 
            <dd> 
              <ul> 
              <li>现价</li> 
              <li style='margin-bottom:6px;'><span><strong class='numfont'>3</strong>元</span></li> 
              <li>原价 264元</li> 
              <li>购买 1人</li> 
              <li>网站 <a href='#' onclick='gotoOutSite("http://www.groupon.cn/html/product/FS/FS4446.html")'>团宝网</a></li> 
              <li>剩余  6天9小时</li> 
              </ul> 
            </dd> 
          </dl> 

          <dl class='midbot'> 

                <dt><a href='http://m.looa.com/m_map?deal_id=6921'><img src='theme/mobile/img/looa_map.gif' /></a></dt> 

                    <dt><img id='cangbtn6921' src='theme/mobile/img/looa_no_cang.gif' onclick="toggleDealCangState('cang',6921,60)" /></dt> 

            <dt><img src='theme/mobile/img/no_phone.gif' /> </dt> 
              </dl>
        </div>

        ************* Repeat *****************

        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS related is :

```
.middigest {word-break:normal;float:left;width:98%;line-height:17px;font-weight:bold;padding:6px 0 8px 0;clear:both;margin:0 1%;}
```

*also,if you want to see the whole CSS,please go to http://m.looa.com/theme/mobile/img/style.css*

Anyone of you has the experience of web developing
for Iphone ? Give me a hand please.

Thanks so much !!!

Comment: Please post the code from your website.

Comment: He gives a link to it... just go there and see the source o_o ?

Comment: I'd say most SO users are more inclined to help if the relevant code is shown here. Also, in the future the website will have changed and the question won't be consistent with the code!

Comment: @ing0  Thanks for you advise,I have now edit my post and attached some code

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an iphone so I can't test it but did you try those CSS properties?

- [White-space](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp)
- [Word-wrap](http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/)
- [Overflow: hidden](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp)